# Convert a comma separated string to list which has a comma at the last

Tags: java

I have the below string which has a comma at the last. I want to convert the string to list. I am using the below code to do it.

```
public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s = "2017-07-12 23:40:00.0,153.76,16.140,60.00,,56.00,";
        String [] items = s.split(",");
        
        List<String> splittedString = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(items));
        for (String s1 : splittedString) {
            System.out.println(s1);
        }
        System.out.println("Here");
    }
}
```

Here the last comma is not being considered as a list element. How can I change this code so that it works?

***Actual Output:-***

```
2017-07-12 23:40:00.0
153.76
16.140
60.00

56.00
Here
```

**Expected output:-**

```
2017-07-12 23:40:00.0
153.76
16.140
60.00

56.00

Here
```

Comment: **Simplify** - try `for (String s1 : s.split(",")) {
   System.out.println(s1);
  }
  System.out.println("Here");` - same output.

Comment: Use a Guava splitter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the split line to:

```
String [] items = s.split(",", -1);
```

and it should do as you expect. This is the version with the limit. Check the [reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)).

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior of String#split.

As per java docs.

> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with
>   the given expression and a limit argument of zero. Trailing empty
>   strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.

Comment: Although this does explain `split` logic, it does not solve OP's issue.

Comment: @NiVeR right that does not solve OP's issue but explains why the issue comes. You have answered the solution already that's why I have not put it in my answer.